# JavaFX: JFreeChart's ChartViewer is not filling the entire tab space

Tags: javafx-8, jfreechart

I am trying to add JFreeChart's ChartViewer object inside JavaFX Tab but corresponding chart is not occupying the entire tab space although I have used AnchorPanes with proper settings. Am I missing something or my approach is wrong?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;

public class VolumeBarChartJava extends Application {
    private TimeSeriesCollection createDataset() {
        TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries("Data");
        ts.add(new Day(1,1,2017), 100.0);
        ts.add(new Day(2,1,2017), 135.0);
        ts.add(new Day(3,1,2017), 140.0);
        ts.add(new Day(4,1,2017), 109.0);
        TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        tsc.addSeries(ts);
        return tsc;        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab = new Tab("Chart");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        tab.setContent(anchorPane);
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(vBox);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
        vBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("BLUE"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        AnchorPane anchorPane1 = new AnchorPane();
        vBox.getChildren().add(anchorPane1);

        TimeSeriesCollection tsc = createDataset();
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Price");
        XYBarRenderer renderer = new XYBarRenderer();
        renderer.setShadowVisible(false);
        renderer.setMargin(.5);
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(tsc, null, rangeAxis, renderer);

        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");
        CombinedDomainXYPlot combinedPlot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(domainAxis);
        combinedPlot.add(plot, 4);

        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Volume Bar Chart", null, combinedPlot, false);
        ChartViewer chartViewer = new ChartViewer(chart);
        anchorPane1.getChildren().add(chartViewer);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(chartViewer, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(chartViewer, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(chartViewer, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(chartViewer, 0.0);
        chartViewer.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("RED"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Volume Bar Chart");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has someone came across similar problem?

I have tried setting preferred size of chartViewer (fixed values) and somehow it worked (although window grows out of screen while maximizing, depending on what values have you used).

    chartViewer.setPrefSize(1080, 760);

How to get the min and max bounds of its container, in this case anchorPane1, so that I can set it as preferred size of chartViewer.

Comment: @trashgod, can you please look into this problem and share your comments